# How can I replicate python list custom sort functionality with Numpy array?

Tags: python, list, numpy, sorting, numpy-ndarray

I have the following code that moves zeros to one end of a standard Python list

```
def _moveZeros(x):    
    if x==0:
        return x
    else:
        return -1

l = [1,0,5,6,0,0,7,2]
l.sort(key=_moveZeros)
print(l)
```

output in this case is [1,5,6,7,2,0,0,0]

How could I accomplish something similar with a Numpy array?

Comment: hmmm  np.sort? Is implemented already.

Comment: Yes but I only want to move the zeros. I do not believe that np.sort accepts the passing of a 'key' parameter to specify a custom evaluation function

Comment: You could construct a new array with the desired sort values, and apply `argsort` to that.  That gives you indices that will reorder the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fancy indexing goes a long way in numpy :)

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,0,5,6,0,0,7,2])

a = np.hstack([a[a != 0], a[a == 0]])
```

I'm not sorting per-se, I'm creating two new views of a, one with all the elements different than 0, and the other one with all the 0s, and then stacking then horizontally as a new array.

If you want numbers other than 0, just replace it with a `k`

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant but it works:

```
import numpy as np
aaa = [1,0,5,6,0,0,7,2]
zero_idxs = np.where(np.array(aaa)==0)[0]
non_zero_idxs = [i for i in range(len(aaa)) if i not in zero_idxs]
np.hstack((np.array(aaa)[non_zero_idxs], np.zeros((len(zero_idxs)), dtype=int)))
```

Returns

```
array([1, 5, 6, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Thanks I had something similar although probably even uglier using argindex. Hoping to avoid looping though!

Comment: I guess for people who are learning, my answer is quite readable, but @Alberto gave the most pythonic answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case the `hstack` approach is good, but in case you need this in a more general case:

You could construct a new array with the desired sort values, and apply argsort to that. That gives you indices that will reorder the original.

```
In [86]: l = np.array([1,0,5,6,0,0,7,2])                                                               
In [87]: m = l==0                                                                                      
In [88]: m                                                                                             
Out[88]: array([False,  True, False, False,  True,  True, False, False])
In [89]: i = np.argsort(m)                                                                             
In [90]: i                                                                                             
Out[90]: array([0, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1, 4, 5])
In [91]: l[i]                                                                                          
Out[91]: array([1, 5, 6, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0])
```